# How to do event.stopPropagation() to react-select input field when arrow keys and enter key pressed in ag grid custom cell editor

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, react-select, ag-grid-react

I'm using ag-grid for records editing.

How do I make a cell editor that does nothing when arrow and enter keys are pressed.

Similar to this code, **but with react-select component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
class TextCellEditor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.textInput = React.createRef();
    }


    onKeyDown(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 39 || event.keyCode === 37) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }

    afterGuiAttached(param) {
        if (this.textInput) this.textInput.current.focus();
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.textInput.current.value;
    }

    isPopup(){
        return true
    }

    isCancelAfterEnd(){
        return false

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.textInput.current.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyDown);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextField
                defaultValue={this.props.value}
                inputProps={{
                    ref:this.textInput
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default TextCellEditor
```

I've tried using refs and `addeventListener` but it doesn't work, here's my current code for react-select cell editor

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CreatableSelect  from "react-select/lib/Creatable"
import { components } from 'react-select'
import axios from "axios"
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


//redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
    setNotification,
    updateFullRecord,
    pushBreadcrumbs,
    pushFullRecord,
    setCFI,
    setFullView,
    pushModalRecord,
    setModalView,
    setCMI,
    toggleModal,
} 
from '../../../actions/ActivityActions'



class ReactSelectCellEditor extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selected : {
                value : "",
                labal : ""
            },
            suggestion :[]
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.MTORef = React.createRef();
        this.InputRef = React.createRef();
        console.log("cell editor props:",this.props)
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.post(this.props.host+"/api/"+this.props.model+"/options", {
            search  : "",
            limit   : 10
        },{
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer "+Cookies.get("accessToken")
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            var arr     = response.data.records
            var result  = arr.map(record =>({
                label :record[this.props.fieldAsLabel],
                value: record[this.props.fieldAsValue]
            }))
            this.setState({
                suggestion : [
                    ...result
                ]
            })
        })
    }

    getLabel=(id)=>{
        axios.get(this.props.host+"/api/"+this.props.model+"/"+id,{
            headers:{
                Authorization:"Bearer "+Cookies.get("accessToken")
            }
        })
    }

    handleClickEdit = () => {
        axios.post(this.props.host+"/api/"+this.props.model+"/"+this.state.selected.value, {
            search  : this.state.selected.value,
            limit   : 10
        },{
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer "+Cookies.get("accessToken")
            }
        }).then((response)=>{
            this.props.pushModalRecord({
                ...response.data,
                formMode:"edit",
                _modal:true
            })
            this.props.saveFormState()
            this.props.setModalView(this.props.form)
            this.props.setCMI(this.props.Activity.currentModalIndex+1)
            this.props.toggleModal()
        })
    }

    handleCreateOption = (inputValue:any) => {
        this.props.pushModalRecord({
            [this.props.fieldAsLabel]:inputValue,
            formMode:"create",
            _modal:true
        })
        this.props.saveFormState()
        this.props.setModalView(this.props.form)
        this.props.setCMI(this.props.Activity.currentModalIndex+1)
        this.props.toggleModal()
    }

    handleChange(selected){
        selected = selected === null?"":selected
        this.setState({
            selected : {
                label : selected.label,
                value : selected.value
            }
        })
    }


    onKeyDown(event) {
        let key = event.which || event.keyCode;
        if (key === 37 ||  // left
            key === 39) {  // right
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }

    afterGuiAttached(param) {
        this.SelectRef.focus()
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.state.selected.value
    }

    isPopup() {
        return true
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div style={{minWidth:"200px",display:"flex"}}>
                <div style={{width:"160px"}}>
                <CreatableSelect 
                    isLoading       = {false}
                    options         = {this.state.suggestion}
                    defaultValue    = {this.props.value !== undefined?{
                        label:this.props.label,
                        value:this.props.value
                    }:null}
                    onChange        = {this.handleChange}
                    onKeyDown       = {event=>this.onKeyDown(event)}
                    onCreateOption  = {this.handleCreateOption}
                    ref             = { ref => { this.MTORef = ref }}
                    isClearable

                />
                </div>
                {this.props.editable?<IconButton onClick={()=>this.handleClickEdit()}>
                    <EditIcon/>
                </IconButton>:""}
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        Global      :state.GlobalReducer,
        Activity    :state.ActivityReducer
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setNotification: (isOpen,message,color)=>{
            dispatch(setNotification(isOpen,message,color))
        },
        updateFullRecord: (data,index) => {
            dispatch(updateFullRecord(data,index))
        },
        setCFI: (index) => {
            dispatch(setCFI(index))
        },
        pushFullRecord: (record) => {
            dispatch(pushFullRecord(record))
        },
        setFullView: (path) => {
            dispatch(setFullView(path))
        },
        pushBreadcrumbs: (data) => {
            dispatch(pushBreadcrumbs(data))
        },
        toggleModal : () => {
            dispatch(toggleModal())
        },
        pushModalRecord : (data) => {
            dispatch(pushModalRecord(data))
        },
        setModalView : (path) => {
            dispatch(setModalView(path))
        },
        setCMI : (data) => {
            dispatch(setCMI(data))
        },
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps,null,{ forwardRef: true })(ReactSelectCellEditor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `suppressKeyboardEvent` callback to ignore arrow and enter keys for the entire grid or for a particular cell. The callback should return true if the grid should suppress the events, or false to continue as normal.

The callback has the following signature:

export interface SuppressKeyboardEventParams extends IsColumnFuncParams {

```
   // the keyboard event the grid received. inspect this to see what key was pressed
   event: KeyboardEvent;

   // whether the cell is editing or not. sometimes you might want to suppress event
   // only when cell is editing.
   editing: boolean;

   node: RowNode; // row node
   data: any; // row data
   column: Column; // column
   colDef: ColDef; // column definition
   context: any; // context object
   api: GridApi | null | undefined; // grid API
   columnApi: ColumnApi | null | undefined; // column API
```

}

The call back function may look like this -

```
function suppressEnterArrow(params) {
      let KEY_LEFT = 37;
      let KEY_UP = 38;
      let KEY_RIGHT = 39;
      let KEY_DOWN = 40;
      let KEY_ENTER = 13;
      let ignoredKeys = [KEY_LEFT, KEY_UP, KEY_RIGHT, KEY_ENTER, KEY_DOWN];
      var event = params.event;
      var key = event.which;
      var suppress = ignoredKeys.include(key) && params.editing && 
         params.colDef.cellEditor === <Your Text Cell Editor>;
      return suppress;
   }
```

You can read more about it here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#suppressKeyboardEvents

Comment: it's still doesn't work although the return value is true

Comment: Have you added this in template `[suppressKeyboardEvent]="suppressEnterArrow"`